# jQuery click() for video element

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm working on SimpleWebRTC. When new party join a room, new video element is added. Now I need to handle click on any of the video element. So I write the code bellow

```
$('video').click(function(e) {
       console.log('clicked');

       e.preventDefault()
});
```

Obviously the block was within jQuery document ready. But I'm not seeing anything on console. The weird thing is when I'm pasting the code above in console of browser, that's working as expected.

I need your guideline to solve the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try running your code inside of webrtcs innit function? `webrtc.on('readyToCall', function () { ... }`

Comment: `$(selector).click()` will add the click event handler only to the elements already on the page. What you want is event delegation (`$(document).on('click', 'video', func)`) There are already a lot of dupes, let me find [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: define a class for video tag. For example: `.chat` like this:

```
<video class="chat" />
```

and use this code:

```
$('video.chat').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log(this);
});
```

or:

```
$(document).on('click', 'video.chat', function (e) {
    console.log(this);
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Last one worked. I'm still confused why **$('video.chat').on('click', function (e) {** not worked but **$(document).on('click', 'video.chat', function (e) {**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give an id to the video element so your script should be

```
$('#video').click(function(e) {
       console.log('clicked');

       e.preventDefault()
});
```

So it should show the text "clicked" on console but I'm not sure there will happen any more